# Can I rest while under the effects of the Meld into Stone spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rests

Suppose my character is sneaking around an enemy encampment, and, just before being discovered by a patrol, spends their last spell-slot to cast [*Meld into Stone*](https://dndbeyond.com/spells/meld-into-stone) on a nearby boulder. In doing so, they effectively avoid detection, but they are now out of spell slots.

Can my character take a rest while the *Meld into Stone* spell is in effect?

The *Meld into Stone* spell does not explicitly restrict my character from taking a rest while inside the stone, as far as I can tell. Is there any reason (e.g. something inherent in the rules of resting, or an issue with balance I may be missing) that my character wouldn't be able to do this while *Meld into Stone* is in effect?

---

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139820) asks what happens when the *Meld into Stone* spell ends naturally — this is tangentially related and interesting, but it doesn't provide an answer to this question.

Comment: Related: Discussions regard resting to be possible. https://www.reddit.com/r/DMAcademy/comments/blf60k/meld_into_stone_shenanigans_5e/ and https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/704119097454297088?s=19

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short rest: yes, Long rest: maybe

The only restriction Meld into Stone places on you is

> **You** otherwise **can't move**.

Short rest is defined as

> A short rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long,
> during which a character **does nothing more strenuous
> than** eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds.

You certainly can take a short rest, as the character by doing nothing and not moving *does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds*.

Long rest is defined as

> A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8
> hours long, during which a character **sleeps or performs
> light activity**: reading, talking, eating, or standing watch
> for no more than 2 hours. If the rest is interrupted by a
> period of strenuous activity—at least 1 hour o f walking,
> fighting, casting spells, or similar adventuring activity—
> the characters must begin the rest again to gain any
> benefit from it.

You may even be able to take a full rest inside the stone, as you need 8 hours, and the spell is just long enough for that. One could however argue that standing in stone is not *sleep or performing light activity*, and therefore does not rest you. It also is not clear if you could sleep, because the spell says "*You remain aware of the passage of time*". While you sleep you are not aware of the passage of time. So for the long rest, this will be up to your DM to decide.

Comment: That is a good catch about not being able to sleep/eat. Thanks!

Comment: In context, "move" clearly refers to using your movement to change positions. You aren't paralyzed or anything like it.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Good point, else you could not cast spells. Will amend.

Comment: [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159387/20855) discusses the difference between "can't move" and "zero movement". Accepted answer: probably not much relevant here. Also, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121584/20855) discusses whether falling prone counts as movement. Accepted answer: possibly not. "You can drop prone without using any of your speed." (Basic Rules, Being Prone)

Comment: Is there anything preventing the caster from lying down inside of the stone and sleeping prone?

Comment: @AllanMills I think up to the DM. It probably depends on if you count it as movement (which seems unlikely, but not impossible) and if you can sleep. The DM could  read "You remain aware of the passage of time" to mean you cannot, as you would be oblivious to time when sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

### Probably

A key part of [*Meld into Stone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meld-into-stone), as Groody the Hobgoblin mentioned, is that you “can't move.”

> You can use your movement to leave the stone where you entered it, which ends the spell. **You otherwise can't move.**

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159387/20855) discusses the difference between “can't move” and “movement speed becomes zero.” [The currently accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159395/20855) is that they both just set your movement speed to zero, but “can't move” has the additional effect that changes to your base speed have no effect. What's important here is that, even being unable to take movement (the game term), you can still *move*. Otherwise (as that answer mentions) you'd have a condition like [Incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) or [Paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed). You just can't leave your spot.

So, under the effects of *Meld into Stone*, you should be able to do things that any other character with no movement speed can do, such as:

- swing your arm, as if wielding a weapon;
- make somatic gestures to cast spells;
- squirm, kick, and wriggle, like someone attempting to escape a [Grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled); or
- fall prone (“You can drop prone without using any of your speed.” (Basic Rules, Ch 9, “Being Prone”)).

So you could potentially just fall down prone and sleep on the ground — assuming that would be a reasonable (if uncomfortable) way to sleep were you *not* melded into stone. You could even change positions in your sleep; you just wouldn't be able to roll away from your spot. (Or have a midnight snack or some water, since your equipment is also melded into the stone.)

### The Most Comfortable Sleep You've Ever Had

Note the following effect of the spell:

> **Nothing of your presence remains** visible or otherwise **detectable by nonmagical senses.**

You, the caster, are not explicitly excluded from this effect. It's entirely possible that, while under the effect of *Meld into Stone*, you are not able to perceive your physical self at all — a perfect isolation chamber. So you may not even have to lie down, because you won't be able to feel your feet or legs. You may just drift in a peaceful absence of physical stimuli, in complete darkness, only vaguely hearing the sounds around you.

It could be incredibly peaceful. Or the loss of stimulus [could lead to hallucinations and complete disorientation](http://www.lesleykinzel.com/90-minutes-in-a-float-tank/).